# 2D and/or 3D plot of a molecule from list of atoms and bonds

Tags: julia

I have a list of atoms with id and position (x,y,z) and a list of bonds with the ids of the two atoms bonded together. What is the best way to create a 2D and/or 3D figure of this molecule in Julia?

Comment: Could you add more details as to what you're trying to plot? Did you want to represent the molecule as just spheres of atoms or visualize the bond interactions as well?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the have both a list of nodes (atoms) and edges (bounds between atoms), consider representing your molecule as a graph and visualize that [graph](https://juliagraphs.github.io/LightGraphs.jl/latest/plotting.html) using available methods from `LightGraph.jl`.

Both 2D and 3D representations are a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [xyz2graph](https://github.com/zotko/xyz2graph) package.